# how to place irregular sized image into a jQuery UI button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

Given a button of a fixed size and an image of an unknown size (but smaller dimensions than the button), how do I dynamically place that graphic onto the button?

This [example only handles something icon sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224537/change-the-icon-of-a-jquery-ui-button-with-own-image), as does this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141607/add-an-image-to-the-jquery-button).

My own attempts end up cropping the image in the lower right.  Hoping to get something robust that works across anything themeroller can spit out.  Here is a live example demonstrating the problem: http://jsbin.com/iliqih/2/edit

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready( function() {
var butt = $("<div class='butt' style='width:500; height:500px' />");
$('body').append(butt);
butt.button();

var cssKey = ".ui-icon.bigIcon";
$(".butt").button("option", {
    icons: {
        primary: 'bigIcon'
    },
    text: false
});

var imgUrl = "http://www.artisancomplete.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/testpattern-hd-1080-480x270.png";
var imgW = 480;
var imgH = 270;
var str = "<style type='text/css'> " + cssKey + " { background-image: url(" + imgUrl + ") !important; width:" + imgW + "px; height:" + imgH + "px; margin-left:-" + (imgW/2) + "; margin-top:-" + (imgH/2) + "} </style>";
$(str).appendTo("head");
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is

> background-position:0

Hereafter is a more replete example wherein `previewW` and `previewH` are the dimensions of your image.

```
"<style type='text/css'>" + cssKey + " {width:" + previewW + "px; height:" + previewH + "px;margin-left:" + (-previewW/2) + "px;margin-top:" + (-previewH/2) + "px;background-position:0;background-image:url(" + imgSrc + ")!important;}</style>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tweaking background-size and see if this helps:

```
var str = "<style type='text/css'> " + cssKey + " { background-image: url(" + imgUrl + ") !important; width:" + imgW + "px; height:" + imgH + "px; margin-left:-" + (imgW/2) + "; margin-top:-" + (imgH/2) + "; background-size: " + (imgW-20) + "px " + (imgH-20) + "px;} </style>";
```